# Dynamically change the size of the popover depending on the content

Tags: ios, swift

I created a pop over for my **UIBarButtonItem**.

```
 @objc func showPopup(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
  let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let ctrl = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Popup") as! Popup
        let nav = UINavigationController()
        nav.pushViewController(ctrl, animated: true)
        nav.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        present(nav, animated: true)
        nav.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender
  }
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvhFp.jpg) are the constraints.
I have several labels placed in my stack view and they can vary in size.

I saw that it is possible to set a preferred explicit size for the **UIViewController** but this would make my layout static.

How can I set a dynamic width and height for the popover depending on its content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an open-source [snippet](https://github.com/elliott-io/SwiftSnippets#popover-messages) for this a few days ago. It includes arrows and passThroughViews so that you can tap them without dismissing the popover, but neither are required parameters.

You can call it from any view controller using:

```
vc.showPopover(message: "Some message for a dynamically-sized popover with a left arrow.", sourceView: self.button, sourceRect: self.button.bounds, arrowDirection: .left, passthroughViews: [button])
```

Show a popover below where a right UIBarButtonItem would be in the nav bar:

```
    guard let navBarView = navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.first else { return }
    let topPadding = self.navigationController?.view.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0
    self.showPopover(message: "This will show up on your rightmost bar button item in your navigation.", sourceView: navBarView, sourceRect: CGRect.init(x: navBarView.frame.width - 40, y: navBarView.frame.height + topPadding, width: 0, height: 0), arrowDirection: .up, passthroughViews: (navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews)!)
```

The first part you need is the PopoverViewController class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class PopoverViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelMessage: UILabel!
    var message:String?
    weak var sendingViewController: UIViewController?
    var arrowDirection: UIPopoverArrowDirection = .any

    let ltPadding: CGFloat = 20 // leading/trailing padding
    let tbPadding: CGFloat = 14 // top/bottom padding
    let arrowPadding: CGFloat = 13 // popover arrow padding
    let dimLevel: CGFloat = 0.6

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let message = self.message {
            self.labelMessage.text = message
        }
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        // dim sendingViewController
        UIView.animate(withDuration: AntimationDuration.fadeInOut.rawValue, animations: {
            self.sendingViewController?.view.alpha = self.dimLevel
        })
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        print("arrowDirection: \(arrowDirection)")

        let item: UIView = self.labelMessage

        guard let superview = item.superview else { return }

        // all constaints must be set for a proper display

        // set centered constraincts
        item.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        item.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        // iOS grows view if there is an arrow, so adjust anchors to fix offset
        if arrowDirection.rawValue == 2 { //.down {
            item.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leadingAnchor, constant: ltPadding).isActive = true
            item.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.trailingAnchor, constant: ltPadding).isActive = true
            item.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.topAnchor, constant: tbPadding).isActive = true
            item.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: superview.bottomAnchor, constant: tbPadding + arrowPadding).isActive = true
            item.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.widthAnchor, constant: -(ltPadding * 2)).isActive = true
            item.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.heightAnchor, constant: -(tbPadding * 2) - arrowPadding).isActive = true
        } else if arrowDirection.rawValue == 1 { //.up {
            item.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leadingAnchor, constant: ltPadding).isActive = true
            item.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.trailingAnchor, constant: ltPadding).isActive = true
            item.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.topAnchor, constant: tbPadding + arrowPadding).isActive = true
            item.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: superview.bottomAnchor, constant: tbPadding).isActive = true
            item.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.widthAnchor, constant: -(ltPadding * 2)).isActive = true
            item.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.heightAnchor, constant: -(tbPadding * 2) - arrowPadding).isActive = true
        } else if arrowDirection.rawValue == 4 { //.left {
            item.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leadingAnchor, constant: ltPadding + arrowPadding).isActive = true
            item.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.trailingAnchor, constant: ltPadding).isActive = true
            item.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.topAnchor, constant: tbPadding).isActive = true
            item.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: superview.bottomAnchor, constant: tbPadding).isActive = true
            item.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.widthAnchor, constant: -(ltPadding * 2) - arrowPadding).isActive = true
            item.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.heightAnchor, constant: -(tbPadding * 2)).isActive = true
        } else if arrowDirection.rawValue == 8 { //.right {
            item.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leadingAnchor, constant: ltPadding).isActive = true
            item.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.trailingAnchor, constant: ltPadding + arrowPadding).isActive = true
            item.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.topAnchor, constant: tbPadding).isActive = true
            item.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: superview.bottomAnchor, constant: tbPadding).isActive = true
            item.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.widthAnchor, constant: -(ltPadding * 2) - arrowPadding).isActive = true
            item.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.heightAnchor, constant: -(tbPadding * 2)).isActive = true
        } else {
            // center if no arrows
            item.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leadingAnchor, constant: ltPadding).isActive = true
            item.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.trailingAnchor, constant: ltPadding).isActive = true
            item.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.topAnchor, constant: tbPadding).isActive = true
            item.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: superview.bottomAnchor, constant: tbPadding).isActive = true
            item.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.widthAnchor, constant: -(ltPadding * 2)).isActive = true
            item.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.heightAnchor, constant: -(tbPadding * 2)).isActive = true
        }
    }

    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        UIViewController.existingPopover = nil

        // restore dimmed sendingViewController
        UIView.animate(withDuration: AntimationDuration.fadeInOut.rawValue, animations: {
            self.sendingViewController?.view.alpha = 1
        })
    }
}
```

You also need the AlwaysPresentAsPopover class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class AlwaysPresentAsPopover : NSObject, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    // `sharedInstance` because the delegate property is weak - the delegate instance needs to be retained.
    private static let sharedInstance = AlwaysPresentAsPopover()

    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .none
    }

    static func configurePresentation(forController controller : UIViewController) -> UIPopoverPresentationController {
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        let presentationController = controller.presentationController as! UIPopoverPresentationController
        presentationController.delegate = AlwaysPresentAsPopover.sharedInstance
        return presentationController
    }
}
```

And the extension functions:

```
extension UIViewController {
    static var existingPopover: PopoverViewController?

    func showPopover(message: String, sourceView: UIView, sourceRect: CGRect, arrowDirection: UIPopoverArrowDirection = [], passthroughViews: [UIView]? = []) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            // init view controller
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popover") as! PopoverViewController
            controller.message = message
            controller.sendingViewController = self
            controller.arrowDirection = arrowDirection

            // set preferred size
            let margins = CGPoint(x: 20, y: 14)
            let textSize = message.size(width: 220)
            let adjustedSize = CGSize(width: textSize.width + (margins.x * 2), height: textSize.height + (margins.y * 2))
            controller.preferredContentSize = adjustedSize

            // create view controller as popover style presentation instead of a normal view controller
            let presentationController = AlwaysPresentAsPopover.configurePresentation(forController: controller)
            presentationController.sourceView = sourceView
            presentationController.sourceRect = sourceRect
            presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = arrowDirection

            // passthroughViews are views that can be tapped without dismissing the popover
            if let views = passthroughViews {
                presentationController.passthroughViews = views
            }

            // if there is an existing presenting view controller, dismiss it before presenting this popover
            if let existing = UIViewController.existingPopover {
                existing.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: {
                        UIViewController.existingPopover = controller
                    })
                })
            } else {
                self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: {
                    UIViewController.existingPopover = controller
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
extension String {
    func size(width:CGFloat = 220.0, font: UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0, weight: .regular)) -> CGSize {
        let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        label.font = font
        label.text = self

        label.sizeToFit()

        return CGSize(width: label.frame.width, height: label.frame.height)

        let squared = square(5)
        print(squared) // prints 25
    }

    func square(_ number: Int) -> Int {
        return number * number
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the popover over a right **BarButtonItem** ? It seems that I can not calculate the rect for it.

Comment: So for example if you have one stack view with 4 labels inside. How would you adjust the size of it?

Comment: There is no way to get a UIView for a right UIBarButtonItem since iOS 11 as far as I know. However you could do this to show the popover below the nav bar 40 points from the right margin. This will also allow user to still tap nav bar without dismissing the popover, if you don't want that, remove the passthroughViews parameter. I've updated my answer with the code.

Comment: And if you want to put a popover near one label in a stack view, use the label's view as the source view.

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer if it solves your problem. :-)

Comment: Can you also dynamically change the size of a popover which has a stack view as a child with 4 labels?

Comment: Do you mean is it possible to create a popover with 4 labels in a stack and have the popover size change? If so, the answer is yes. However, those labels and sizes would need to be added and calculated. This extension only has one label in the popover. A simple hack would be to assign the `message` with "\r" to go to the next line between each value you want to assign.